# OpenMP reduction with Eigen::VectorXd

Tags: c++, openmp, eigen, clang++, eigen3

I am attempting to parallelize the below loop with an OpenMP reduction;

```
#define EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Eigenvalues>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

VectorXd integrand(double E)
{
    VectorXd answer(500000);
    double f = 5.*E + 32.*E*E*E*E;
    for (int j = 0; j !=50; j++)
        answer[j] =j*f;
    return answer;
}

int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    double start = 0.;
    double end = 1.;
    int n = 100;
    double h = (end - start)/(2.*n);

    VectorXd result(500000);
    result.fill(0.);
    double E = start;
    result = integrand(E);
    #pragma omp parallel
    { 
    #pragma omp for nowait
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        E = start + (2*j - 1.)*h;
        result = result + 4.*integrand(E);
        if (j != n){
            E = start + 2*j*h;
            result = result + 2.*integrand(E);
        }
    }
    }
    for (int i=0; i <50 ; ++i)
        cout<< i+1 << " , "<< result[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is definitely faster in parallel than without, but with all 4 threads, the results are hugely variable. When the number of threads is set to 1, the output is correct.
I would be most grateful if someone could assist me with this...

I am using the clang compiler with compile flags;

```
clang++-3.8 energy_integration.cpp -fopenmp=libiomp5
```

If this is a bust, then I'll have to learn to implement `Boost::thread`, or `std::thread`...

Comment: Add `firstprivate(params) reduction(+:result_int)` to your `parallel` directive, remove the `critical` and try again...

Comment: @Gilles thank you for your response.. I have edited my code so that the first `#pragma` statement reads `#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(params) reduction(+:result_int)`, the second `#pragma` statement remains as is, and all subsequent `#pragma` statements are removed. The program then yields the runtime error: `....const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >]: Assertion aLhs.rows() == aRhs.rows() && aLhs.cols() == aRhs.cols()' failed.
Aborted` - I can assure that both kspace and result_int have the same number of elements and dimensionality

Comment: Can you round out your example to a full [mcve]? Also, does the serial version work as expected?

Comment: @AviGinsburg thank you, please see above, now edited. Yes, the serial version works as expected

Comment: This is not Complete. There is no definition of `integrand(...)` nor is your code compilable. You also have not answered if the serial version returns the correct result.

Comment: @AviGinsburg this is now amended, the code above is a very stripped down version of what I am trying to accomplish, but I believe the answer will help my purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not define a custom reduction for OpenMP to reduce the Eigen objects. I'm not sure if clang supports user defined reductions (see [OpenMP 4 spec](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf), page 180). If so, you can declare a reduction and add `reduction(+:result)` to the `#pragma omp for` line. If not, you can do it yourself by changing your code as follows:

```
VectorXd result(500000); // This is the final result, not used by the threads
result.fill(0.);
double E = start;
result = integrand(E);
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // This is a private copy per thread. This resolves race conditions between threads
    VectorXd resultPrivate(500000);
    resultPrivate.fill(0.);
#pragma omp for nowait// reduction(+:result) // Assuming user-defined reductions aren't allowed
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        E = start + (2 * j - 1.)*h;
        resultPrivate = resultPrivate + 4.*integrand(E);
        if (j != n) {
            E = start + 2 * j*h;
            resultPrivate = resultPrivate + 2.*integrand(E);
        }
    }
#pragma omp critical
    {
        // Here we sum the results of each thread one at a time
        result += resultPrivate;
    }
}
```

The error you're getting ([in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495250/openmp-reduction-with-eigenvectorxd#comment68476881_40597452)) seems to be due to a size mismatch. While there isn't a trivial one in your code itself, don't forget that when OpenMP starts each thread, it has to initialize a private `VectorXd` per thread. If none is supplied, the default would be `VectorXd()` (with a size of zero). When this object is the used, the size mismatch occurs. A "correct" usage of `omp declare reduction` would include the initializer part:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction (+: VectorXd: omp_out=omp_out+omp_in)\
     initializer(omp_priv=VectorXd::Zero(omp_orig.size()))
```

`omp_priv` is the name of the private variable. It gets initialized by `VectorXd::Zero(...)`. The size is specified using `omp_orig`. The standard 
(page 182, lines 25-27) defines this as:

> The special identifier **omp_orig** can also appear in the initializer-clause and it will refer to the storage of the original variable to be reduced.

In our case (see full example below), this is `result`. So `result.size()` is 500000 and the private variable is initialized to the correct size.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

VectorXd integrand(double E)
{
    VectorXd answer(500000);
    double f = 5.*E + 32.*E*E*E*E;
    for (int j = 0; j != 50; j++)   answer[j] = j*f;
    return answer;
}

#pragma omp declare reduction (+: Eigen::VectorXd: omp_out=omp_out+omp_in)\
     initializer(omp_priv=VectorXd::Zero(omp_orig.size()))

int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    double start = 0.;
    double end = 1.;
    int n = 100;
    double h = (end - start) / (2.*n);

    VectorXd result(500000);
    result.fill(0.);
    double E = start;
    result = integrand(E);

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result)
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        E = start + (2 * j - 1.)*h;
        result += (4.*integrand(E)).eval();
        if (j != n) {
            E = start + 2 * j*h;
            result += (2.*integrand(E)).eval();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
        cout << i + 1 << " , " << result[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. This gets me a 2.17x speed increase with 4 threads going. The user defined reduction didn't work for me, but the run-time error makes me wonder whether it is to do with Eigen, rather than Clang. EDIT just tried this with g++ which doesn't even compile `‘result’ has invalid type for ‘reduction’`

Comment: What runtime error occurred? With what code? It may also be that Eigen types don't play nicely with omp, I haven't tried.

Comment: I think you're right about Eigen and omp. I have tested this on the code I posted with your user defined reduction. The runtime error is the same even if only one thread is set, excerpt shown as output too long: `[BinaryOp = Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double>, Lhs = const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Rhs = const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_multiple_op<doub‌​le>, const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >]: Assertion \`aLhs.rows() == aRhs.rows() && aLhs.cols() == aRhs.cols()' failed. Aborted` I hasten to add, the alternative method you outline, works a treat.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum, I'll do some further reading on OpenMP from the manual you link. I have tried the code you posted with `omp declare reduction` but I get a compile error. Clang yields `error: expected an OpenMP directive
#pragma omp declare reduction(+: VectorXd: omp_out=omp_out+omp_in)\ ` and g++ yields `In function ‘int main()’:
energy_integral_test.cpp:36:45: error: ‘result’ has invalid type for ‘reduction’
 #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result)` . You have found a solution that works for me though

Comment: Did you add the initializer part? The '\' was just to keep the line from being too long.

Comment: `#pragma omp declare reduction (+: Eigen::VectorXd: omp_out=omp_out+omp_in) initializer(omp_priv=VectorXd::Zero(omp_orig.size()))` yields the same error (this is all as one line)

Comment: That looks like it's from an old version of gcc (<4.9) before OpenMP4.0 was supported. It works for me with gcc 5.X both on Ubuntu and Windows (mingw).

Comment: yes, I'm using gcc 4.8. Clang only supports OpenMP3.1 at this stage, but I believe OpenMP4.0 and OpenMP4.5 are being implemented in future builds